# Cocoa window - how to position in top right

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I need to position my *NSWindow* in the top right of the screen, just below the menubar (like notifications). What is the best approach for doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the window position to top right corner using:

```
- (void)setWindowPosition
{
    NSPoint pos;
   pos.x = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].origin.x + [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].size.width - [_window frame].size.width ;
    pos.y = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].origin.y + [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].size.height - [_window frame].size.height  ;
   [_window setFrameOrigin : pos];
}
```

Call this method in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, and also register the  `windowDidResizeNotification` to handle the resize event as:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self setWindowPosition];   //set window pos

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:nil];    //register resize notification

}
```

Now in your notification handler method, again update the window position.

```
- (void)handleNotification: (id) sender
{
     [self setWindowPosition];
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `NSScreen.main` is not necessarily the same screen that contains the menu bar. You can use `NSScreen.screens.first` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`[NSScreen visibleFrame]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScreen/visibleFrame):

(untested)

```
// Assumes self is the NSWindow subclass
NSRect sf = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame];
NSRect wf = self.frame;
self.frame = NSMakeRect(NSWidth(sf) - NSWidth(wf), NSHeight(sf) - NSHeight(wf),
                        wf.size.width, wf.size.height);
```

Comment: I'm using a iMac having a resolution 2.560x1.440, but the height of the visibleFrame is just 1.324. It seems that the height of both the dock and menu bar is subtracted from this frame. As my origin is the bottom-left of my screen, the height of the dock if missing in the calculation. How should I handle this?

Comment: @DennisMadsen Isn't that exactly what you want?  I suggested `visibleFrame` rather than `frame` precisely for this reason.  Anyway if you don't want to consider the menu then use `frame` instead of `visibleFrame`.

Comment: It's very good, that the height of the menu has been subtracted, but the fact that the dock is subtracted as well, is not very helpful, since the frame of my window is from the bottom-left of my screen -- and therefore the vertical position just below the menubar would be *visibleFrame.size.height+heightOfDock*.

Comment: Another issue. I'm using auto-layout on this window. The size (width) of the window grows, if for instance a longer text is inserted into a *NSTextField*. This means, that I need to recalculate this frame, when the controls changes. How can I do that?